# compute a difference( dB) between two BER curves

Tags: digital-communications

[image]

For example, given these 4 curves and I would like to compute a loss/difference between BER of BPSK and BER 8PSk in dB.

How to do that? let say for BER 10^-2

Answer (score 0):

For the segment you show, there's no single number that describes what you want – your lines need to be parallel for that to become a single number.

So, your question can't be answered *in general* from the diagram, as you did, you'll have to take a fixed BER; and then, I don't really understand the question – that's a horizontal line in your plot. You can read the difference directly from where the curves hits that line.

You can, however, talk about an *asymptotic gain* if you are able to figure out how these curves continue for large SNRs (you'll have to run with sufficiently many points at say around 23 dB Eb/N0, in my experience, for 16-PSK); at some point, these curves become sufficiently parrallel. Then you can measure the difference in Eb/N0 necessary to achieve the same BER. (that's a horizontal line through the graph; you measure the distance of intersection of curves with the horizontal line.)

Note that this **does not** work the same way for BER achieved with a given Eb/N0. (i.e. you can't just measure the vertical distance, that doesn't converge as well.)